# Why does Apache find the website directory automatically?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config

The only `<Directory>` I have among *all Apache config files* is:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Actually the real directory on server is `/var/www/html/`. The directory `/var/www/` has no file, but only the subdir `html`.

So accessing the root of my website should fail, because `/var/www/index.html` doesn't exist. But it doesn't fail, the content of `/var/www/html/index.html` is displayed, even if I didn't specify it in the config file.

**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Directory>` sections cover the specified directory and any subdirectory.

Something like `DocumentRoot`, `VirtualDocumentRoot`, `Alias`, `RewriteRule`, or `FallBackResource` could exist in an Apache config file or .htaccess that maps / to /var/www/html without any <Directory> section explicitly listing it.

*Edit: if `apachectl -S` shows `Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"` even if this is specified nowhere in your config files, this means that this value is compiled-in default in your Apache build.*

Comment: As discussed on IRC, I added: *if `apachectl -S` shows `Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"` even if this is specified nowhere in your config files, this means that this value is compiled-in default in your Apache build.*, that was true for me